# Phonegap: save files on Ios

Tags: ios, cordova

I make an app for ios, but have a rare problem.

In app are a button for record sound. That's work fine, after save the sound in created folder named "Gueopic". When file are saved, automatic put into a list of recorded sounds for play wherever you wont (The tipical app for recording ;) ).

If I run the app on xcode simulator, all works fine! (create folder, record, aand play.).

But when run the app on a mobile don't work. I use the error messages for localize it, but not have any error. I think that the error is on create folder or on seve file in this folder, but i dont know.

The name of this file are put in list of elements correctly, but dont execute the sound.

I use the same code for take a photo and save. And have a same problem. On mobile when i wont put image on table, i can see a blank div but not an image. If i click on this (i put a alert for that), can see a route of image are correcly. Image not is saved?

The code:

```
function recordSound(){



    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});


    function captureSuccess(mediaFiles){

        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            guardarFile(mediaFiles[i]);

        }


    }



    function captureError(){console.log("error")}


    function guardarFile(file){

    console.log("comensa a guardar");

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///"+file.fullPath, resolveOnSuccess, err);



    }

    function resolveOnSuccess(entry){
        console.log("fins aki b");

        var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    //new file name
    var newFileName = n + ".wav";
    var myFolderApp = "Gueopic";

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
    //The folder is created if doesn't exist
    fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp,
                    {create:true, exclusive: false},
                    function(directory) {
                        entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName,  successMove, err);
                    },
                    err);
                    },
    err);

            function successMove(nou){

                console.log("nou: "+nou.fullPath);
                var a = nou.fullPath;
                alert("guardat a:"+nou.fullPath)
//localStorage.fully = a;

var arr = a.split("/");
arr.pop();

var f  ="";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    f = f+arr[i]+"/";
}


localStorage.fully = f;
    newObject.sound = newFileName;

                }
    }
    function err(){console.log("error")}



}
```

After only use a localstorage.fully for take a path.

We are an autism association and i'm not a profesional programer (nor english linguist :P ), your help are very important!
Thanks!!!

Comment: What version of phonegap are you using? Did you set the right in the config file?

Comment: Using 2.9.1 version. I dont know if set right. Don't touch the config.xml file. Use a default config.

Comment: here is a link for that http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture check if the permission are set correctly

Comment: OK, I include this line '<plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />' into a plugin tags. Now I do not have an iPhone to test. it is probably that the error. Thank you very much, proves it when I can.

Comment: You have to do the same for the picture http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Comment: @Phyron Have you resolved this scenario, for me also the same thing required, I am getting images and videos saved but into TMP directory. I would like to use iOS Document directory instead.